# How to solve this (http://codingbat.com/prob/p168357) 'codingbat' example efficiently?

Tags: java, logic

I came across this problem on codingbat.com : [Problem](http://codingbat.com/prob/p168357)

Problem:

Given an array of ints, return true if the array contains two 7's next to each other, or there are two 7's separated by one element, such as with {7, 1, 7}.

has77([1, 7, 7]) → true

has77([1, 7, 1, 7]) → true

has77([1, 7, 1, 1, 7]) → false

I solved it but my approach is not that efficient. The code of my solution is large compared to the problem. Can anybody show me how to solve this problem in a smart way.

My code:

```
public boolean has77(int[] nums) {
  int i = 0;
  int arraylength = 0;
  while(i != nums.length){
    if(nums[i] == 7){
      arraylength++;
    }
    i++;
  }
  int[] sevens = new int[arraylength];
  if(arraylength == 0){
    return false;
  }
  i =0;
  int j = 0;
  while(i != nums.length){
    if(nums[i] == 7){
       sevens[j] = i;
       j++;
    }
  i++;
 }
 i = 0;
 while(i != arraylength-1){
     if(sevens[i+1] - sevens[i]==1 || (sevens[i+1]- sevens[i]==2)){
      return true;
 }
i++;
}
 return false;
 }
```

Comment: Efficiently? Only iterate the array once. If current element is a 7, and previous element or the one before it is also a 7, return true.

Comment: At: The down voter , it will be better to explain the reason for down vote so that I will take care next time. Just a request!

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but you should not just provide a link. Links may not work, so always include the pertinent parts in your question. You can still provide link for full reference.

Comment: @Andreas can you post the code plz?

Comment: Nope, but I did repost my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will tell you *how* to do it, but will not give you the code. Writing the code is for you to do, since you chose at accept the challenge on CodingBat.

*More efficiently solution:* Only iterate the array once. If current element is a 7, and previous element or the one before it is also a 7, return `true`.

Comment: The logic you are talking about will not work if the function argument is an array:  [7, 7, 1, 1, 7]

Comment: Why not? I tried coding it like that, and it worked perfectly the first time.

Comment: public boolean has77(int[] nums) {
  int i = 0;
  int indexseven = 0;
  while(i != nums.length){
    if(nums[i] == 7){
       indexseven = i;
      }
    i++;
  }
  if(nums[indexseven-1]==7){
    return true;
  }
  if(nums[indexseven-2]==7){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

Comment: What is the purpose of `indexseven`? Get rid of it. --- Why do you use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop for iterating the array? --- Ok, you now removed that comment, but why would you record the index of seven? Where in my answer did it say to do that?

Comment: I finally succeeded... Thanks for your help, I am posting the code as an answer. Please check it for any improvements...

Answer (score 0):

I finally cracked the question.
Here is the code:

```
   public boolean has77(int[] nums) {
      int i = 0;
      while(i != nums.length){
          if(nums[i]==7 && i!=0){
              if(nums[i-1] == 7){
                  return true;
              }
          }
         if(nums[i]==7 && i>1){
             if(nums[i-2] == 7){
                 return true;
             }
         }
         i++;
      }
   return false;
   }
```

Comment: Three comments: 1) If you move `if(nums[i]==7 && i>1)` inside `if(nums[i]==7 && i!=0)`, then you won't need to check `nums[i]==7` twice. 2) If you start with `i = 1` then you won't need `i!=0`. 3) Why do you use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop for iterating the array?

Comment: Thanks for the review. Well I use while loop for no reason. Is it not a good practice?

Comment: It is better practice to use a `for` loop for this kind of loop, because it keeps the `int i = 0`, `i != nums.length`, and `i++` together as a single construct, i.e. the entire loop logic is in one place. It also makes the `i` variable scoped to the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
public boolean has77(int[] nums) {
  for(int i=0;i<=nums.length-2;i++){
    if(nums[i]==7&&nums[i+1]==7)
    return true;
    for(int j=0;j<nums.length-2;j++){
       if(nums[j]==7&&nums[j+2]==7) 
       return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easy and efficient way to do this.

```
public boolean has77(int[] nums) {
  for(int i=0;i<nums.length-2;i++){
    if((nums[i]==7 && nums[i+1]==7) || (nums[i+1]==7 && nums[i+2]==7)|| 
    (nums[i]==7 && nums[i+2]==7)){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```